# Removing an empty list of objects from a nested sublist

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object, `Foo` which contains a `List<Bar>`.

`Bar` contains a `List<Baz>`.

`Baz` contains a `List<Qux>`.

`Qux` has a property I want to compare.

If I have `List<Foo>`, how do I filter out all `Foo` objects from the list where `List<Qux>` is empty?

**EDIT**
Updated my question to more appropriately reflect my problem.

Comment: Assuming your `listFoo` is your list of `Foo` then we have `var filteredListFoo = listFoo.Select(bar => bar.Select(baz => baz.Select(qux => qux.myproperty == 'somevalue')))`

Comment: Your edit suggests that the structure is recursive. Is this true? It would make the question a lot easier to understand and answering much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @31eee384 for putting me on the right track.

I also incorporated the `Except()` extension to remove the empty lists. I'm sure there is a more efficient method of writing this, so, please post if you know of one.

This is the extension method that I created.

```
internal static List<Foo> OnlyWithQuxs(this List<Foo> model)
{
    var foosToRemove = new List<Foo>();

    foreach (var foo in model)
    {
        var barsToRemove = new List<Bar>();

        foreach (var bar in foo.bars)
        {
            var bazWithQux = new List<Baz>();
            var bazsToRemove = new List<Baz>();

            foreach (var baz in bar.bazs)
            {

                baz.Quxs = GetbazQuxs(baz.Id)
                    .Where(qux => qux.Property == someValue)
                    .ToList();

                bazWithQux.Add(baz);

                if (baz.Quxs == null || baz.Quxs.Count() == 0)
                    bazsToRemove.Add(baz);
            }

            bar.bazs = bazWithQux.Except(bazsToRemove).ToList();

            if (bar.bazs == null || bar.bazs.Count() == 0)
                barsToRemove.Add(bar);
        }

        foo.bars = foo.bars.Except(barsToRemove).ToList();

        if (foo.bars == null || foo.bars.Count() == 0)
            foosToRemove.Add(foo);
    }

    return model.Except(foosToRemove).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep a `Foo` when there exists some `Qux` under it with a certain value, do this:

```
List<Foo> foos = ...;
IEnumerable<Foo> query = foos
    .Where(foo => foo.Bars
        .SelectMany(bar => bar.Bazs)
        .SelectMany(baz => baz.Quxs)
        .Any(qux => qux.SomeProperty == someValue));
```

If you want to keep a `Foo` when all `Qux` under it have a certain value, replace `Any` with `All`.

Comment: I through your code in the mix and it produced the same data that I initially had. I edited my question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm on the road. If List<Qux> is empty, how do I filter out that Baz from List<Baz> and the same for each parent?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with more clear syntax (like for me in that case)

```
List<Foo> lst = GetFooList();
var foos = from foo in lst
           from bar in foo.Bars
           from baz in bar.Bazs
           from qux in baz.Quxs
           where qux.Property != somevalue
           select foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foos.Where(f=>f.Bars.All(bar=>bar.Bazs.All(baz=>baz.Quxs.Any())>))
```

This should work where every `baz` will not have an empty `List<Qux>`

```
var foos = new List<Foo>
            {
                new Foo {Bars = new List<Bar> {new Bar { Bazs = new List<Baz> { new Baz { Quxs = new List<Qux> { new Qux()} } } } } },
                new Foo {Bars = new List<Bar> {new Bar { Bazs = new List<Baz> { new Baz { Quxs = new List<Qux> { new Qux()} } } } } },
                 new Foo {Bars = new List<Bar> {new Bar { Bazs = new List<Baz> { new Baz { Quxs = new List<Qux> { } } } } } },

            };

            var r = foos.Where(f => f.Bars.All(bars=>bars.Bazs.All(baz=>baz.Quxs.Any()))).ToList();

 class Foo
{
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public List<Baz> Bazs { get; set; }
}

class Baz
{
    public List<Qux> Quxs { get; set; }
}

class Qux { }
```

Comment: This returns List<Foo> where List<Qux> is empty rather than a nonempty List<Qux>

Comment: @Ian, that's weird, because I get two records if I run that query against that class structure.

Comment: I'll rerun it on Friday when I get into the shop. My test on your code was based on your original response.... Stay tuned!

Comment: I ran it again in my code and came up with the same results. I was able to remove the `Foo`s using `foos.Where(f=>f.Bars.Any(bar=>bar.Bazs.Any(baz=>baz.Quxs.Any()))` How can I do the same with the `Bars` and `Bazs`?